# Two nonclustered index have similar column for index_keys in sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

There is a tableA created without index and there is data existing in the table.
To faster the read/write for performance, indexes are needed.

There is tableA with indexes as below:

tableA_IDX  nonclustered located on PRIMARY COL1
tableA_IDX2 nonclustered located on PRIMARY COL1, COL2, COL3
tableA_IDX3 nonclustered located on PRIMARY COL1, COL4, COL2

**COL1/2/3/4 has varchar(15)

both tableA_IDX2 and tableA_IDX3 have the same index_keys: COL1, COL2

Questions:
Should they combine together as one index to faster the read as below:
tableA_IDX2 nonclustered located on PRIMARY COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ?

Comment: How on earth can anyone tell what indexes are needed when we have no idea what the table structure is or what queries you run against it? You need to profile this yourself.

Comment: The first decision is whether you want a clustered index. You can have only one - there are many discussions about choosing the most appropriate one you can find by searching. Heaps (tables without clustered indexes) are rare but do have a purpose. Make sure you understand how a heap works before you attempt anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The index on `COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4` could be used where the index on `COL1, COL2, COL3` is used. Its size would be larger of course.

The index on `COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4` could be used where the index on `COL1, COL4, COL2` is used but not as efficiently. Consider this example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE COL1 = 'x'
AND   COL4 = 'y'
AND   COL2 BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

The index on `COL1, COL4, COL2` would use *index seek*. However the index on `COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4` would first require SQL Server to seek the portion of index where COL1 = 'x' and COL2 between 10 and 20, but then it will have to *scan* that portion to locate the values where COL4 = 'y' which just happens to be at the bottom of index. This could be fast or slow, depending on how the values in COL3 are distributed.

So yes, you can combine the two indexes but you first need to evaluate the impact on performance.

Comment: Understand, Thank you Salman A :)

Comment: I evaluate the performance for the combined index, it is slower. So i will proceed to use these 3 indexes. Thanks again Salman!!